# How to add conditions between parser arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

I have 2 arguments `start_date` and `end_date` I want to ensure that the user gives a string of the date they want in the format dd-mm-yyyy and that `start_date` is a date before `end_date`, I've already made a function to check the date is indeed a date but can't figure out how to compare the 2 arguments.

```
def valid_date(s):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d-%m-%Y")
    except ValueError:
        msg = "Not a valid date: '{0}'.".format(s)
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)


parser.add_argument(
    type=valid_date,
)
```

Comment: After `strptime`, just compare `start_date < end_date`? If you are asking how to check this in `optparse`, you should probably tag the question accordingly.

Comment: Oh yeah of course! I can already tell this Friday is going to be a slow one, thanks buddy, I'm using argparse, I'll add a tag now :)

Comment: I'd test the 2 arguments after parsing.  `type` testing for one string is easy.  You might be able to write an condition test using one or two custom Action classes, but it won't save on code.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the Moment library to do so. If you are going to calculate more complex things with time and dates then do not go with raw/ self-written code and go with moment library.Here I am attaching the
>   library you can use to play with dates and time
>   https://pypi.org/project/moment/0.0.14/